# Is there a way I can get a string value out of an enum in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public enum RoleType
{
    Default = 10,
    Guest = 20,
    User = 30,
    Admin = 40,
    Super = 50
}
```

Is there any way that I could get have some kind of toString method in the enum that would give me the strings "Default", "Guest" .. etc    I don't mind to hard code these in one by one or even have a dictionary with the values hardcoded twice inside the enum. I would just like to keep everything self contained inside of my enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string str =Enum.GetName(typeof(RoleType), obj);
```

obj should be the value you want the name for

Comment: I think the method name is `GetNames`

Comment: I didn't expect this existed. Is there a way I can get all of the names and values? Sorry it's a bit out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @Shahar You're right; I misread the question and thought the answer to be `GetNames`

Answer (score 2):

How about `ToString()`?

```
Console.WriteLine(RoleType.User);

> User

Console.WriteLine(RoleType.User.ToString());

> User
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RoleType.Guest.ToString()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    public enum RoleType {
        Default = 10,
        Guest = 20,
        User = 30,
        Admin = 40,
        Super = 50
    }


    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(RoleType.Guest.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1=Enum.GetNames(typeof(RoleType), object);
```